# Can't find or load main class to make a Javafx jar in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: windows-10, java, user-interface, intellij-idea, ide

I made my first Javafx Application in IntellIJ IDEA it runs perfectly but i have a problem.

I can't make an executable jar for this Application.
To be more explicit whenever i try to search for the main class i can't find it in the artifact tab.

I tried making a normal jar (in the artifacts menu they give you the choice between normal jar and javafx application jar) and the main is detected.

[image]

Comment: i've added a picture to the post

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209569). You can type the fully qualified class name manually as the workaround (`foo.bar.MyClass`).

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).